# How to use string formatting with specific nubmer of digits on hex Ascii

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex, python-2.x

In Python 2.7, I want to convert hex ascii number to itself using string formating with specific number of digits

Example:

```
hexNumber='9'
print '%02x' % (hexNumber)
```

Output:

```
09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *string*, just zero-fill it to the desired width using [`str.zfill()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```
hexNumber.zfill(2)
```

The `%x` formatter is for *integers* only.

Demo:

```
>>> hexNumber = '9'
>>> hexNumber.zfill(2)
'09'
```

Comment: But the number of zeroes is not always the same.
I may have need for 0 zeroes or even 4 zeroes.

Comment: @GuyMarkman: leave that to the `str.zfill()` method. It'll add enough zeros to give you a string of the requested width. Note that I told it to pad out to 2 characters, but only 1 `0` was added.

Comment: @GuyMarkman: for your *example* you'd never add 4 zeros, because you told the string formatter to pad out to 2 digits too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of Python's [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=format%20mini#format-specification-mini-language) command for string formatting. This allows you to specify a fill character, in this case `0` and a width as follows:

```
print "{:0>2s}".format('9')
```

This would display:

```
09
```

Answer (score 0):

*print(("{0:05X}".format(int("1C", 16))))*

0001C

*print(("{0:05X}".format(0x1C)))*

0001C